# Adobe AIR for Mobile: default Samsung keyboard text input bug

Tags: android, apache-flex, air, samsung-mobile

I am experiencing a strange bug only on Samsung mobile phones that are running Androi 4+.
With Adobe AIR, every textInput is not suitable for use. The beginning of the entered word is repeated on every char input. 
Here is the behaviour:

When I enter "ABC"
The input text is "AABAABAABAABAABAABC" (or sometimes known words from the dictionary)

It seems to add the whole content of the text input on each key press. Making the words repeated several times.
It also seems to be an autosuggestion (from the phone's dictionary) related bug.

The textInput is declared this way:

```
<s:TextInput id="tin" autoCapitalize="all" autoCorrect="false" 
             maxChars="19" restrict="0-9A-Za-z_\-" width="100%" 
             itemCreationPolicy="immediate"/>
```

Others devices are just running fine, even on HTC running Android 4.1, older versions or others manufacturers.
This bug has also been seen on Swype keyboards (third-party system keyboards).

Do you have a workaround to make it work?

Thanks

EDIT: The worst behaviours are caused by the `restrict` property. Without that, the text input is still bugged, but less. I filed those bugs at bugbase.adobe.com, please vote for it:

1. [TextInput's restrict attribute makes user interaction totally unusable](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3367699)
2. [TextInput's autoCorrect attribute has no effect](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3640670)
3. [TextInput component ignores autoCapitalize, autoCorrect, and softKeyboardType properties when setting a custom skin](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLEX-29024)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the mobile textInput, Adobe has really screwed us with Flex 4.6.
Set the skin class to `spark.skins.mobile.TextInputSkin` and you should be good to go.

Comment: To go further on keyboard handling, there is another caret position bug with the Swype http://www.swype.com/ keyboard. Any auto-corrected word is added after the current cursor position. With this kind of keyboard you are not able to delete this word. Bug occurs only with this third-party keyboard... The spark.skins.mobile.TextInputSkin doesn't help. Any idea?

Comment: Not a clue sorry. I never worked with the Swype keyboard and currently I don't have an Android device at hand. We really need to stress the `TextInput` issues of 4.6 in the Apache Flex Jira, especially since it constantly changes its behavior (i.e 3.1 to 3.2 to 3.3).